# Validation order with filter

Tags: java, swing, filter

I have the following code:

```
String sPassword = pssfldLoginPsw.getText();
boolean match = sPassword.matches("[a-zA-Z+]+[0-9+]+[&@!#+]+");

if (match==false) 
{                            
    System.out.println("Didn't Work");                    
}

if (match==true) 
{
    System.out.println("Work"); 
}
```

And this works great if I input `H1@` or `G2!`. However if I input something like `!G2` or `G@5` it sets `match=false`. Since this field needs to contain a letter, number and a non-aplhanumerical character but it should be able to have them in any order. How would I do this?

Comment: I suggest not doing it with one regular expression. Instead try 3 of them.

Comment: What are the possible values you want to allow? I should be able to give you an accurate regexp, but I need to know what it is you want to allow. Your current regexp only allows for wildcards at the end of the password for example. So it is correct in rejecting passwords with wildcards in the middle.

Comment: I would like it to validate so as long as it has a letter(upper or lower case), a number, and a non alphanumerical character (or wildcard as I think you call it) anywhere in the password it would be accepted, otherwise I would not like it to be accepted. @Ractoc

Comment: I would also like multiple repeats of each type to be allowed anywhere in it. For example P@ssW0rd360!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some further research and found out `"((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})"` would do what I needed it to do.

```
String sPassword = pssfldLoginPsw.getText();
boolean match = sPassword.matches("((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})");

if (match==false) 
{                            
    System.out.println("Didn't Work");                    
}

if (match==true) 
{
    System.out.println("Work"); 
}
```

`(?=.*\d)` must contains one digit from 0-9

`(?=.*[a-z])` must contains one lowercase characters

`(?=.*[A-Z])` must contains one uppercase characters

`(?=.*[@#$%])` must contains one special symbols in the list "@#$%"

`.`   match anything with previous condition checking

`{6,20}` length at least 6 characters and maximum of 20